# Unit test unresolved symbol when using Objective-C++

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, objective-c++

I am trying to create unit tests to my project, I have workspace with several projects with tens of static libraries and apps. So, I created a new project for static library in this workspace and added Cocoa Touch UnitTest bundle to it. Then I added a test for one of the functions in one of the libraries in this workspace, lets say library X, I also added link dependency to my unit test bundle to lib X. But when I run unit tests (Cmd + U). I get linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:"_OSVersion", referencedfrom:-[MyUnitTest testMethodFromLibX] in MyUnitTestTest.o "_methodFromLibX", referenced symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Why test bundle is not linking with library X? I can see libX.a and MyUnitTests.octet in build folder.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, thanks all, I found cause of the problem - my libX was Objective-C++ library, so linker mangled all names, but my Unit-Tests were Objective-C library, so when it was linking it obviously couldn't find method or class by name, since linkage was different. So, I convert unit-tests into Objective-C++ library(just changed *.m -> *.mm) and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests run in the simulator, and so every library need to have a x386 version. You can use the command line to examine each - i believe "file lib.a" does this but a quick google search will turn up the name.

Comment: Thanks David, the thing is that library X is used in my iOS App which is successfully running under simulator, so I am pretty sure that lib X has x386 version.

Comment: If you can upload it of a reduced demo project me and others can see what the problem is.